# Send_File and Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, stream

I am trying to use send_file to stream 1000 pictures on the browser, and simulate video streaming. I currently run my server (locally) using thin, and I have this in my controller:

```
send_file 'bg.jpg', :type => 'image/jpg', :disposition => 'inline'
```

I did not find any tutorials that explain send file, and I heard that I have to use ngnix to make it work. Any help streaming the pictures?

The page returns "Cannot read file bg.jpg", but the file is there, in the assets/images/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
send_file 'assets/images/bg.jpg', :type => 'image/jpg', :disposition => 'inline'
```

Since send_file is not an assets method you will need to supply the full path to it.